# VBA Hide formulas and Protect all sheets in excel

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying the below code to protect and hide formulas of all sheets.

However, it does works with limited sheets instead of all sheet.  I have tried several ways to do it but it doesn't support.

It would be great to see your support on this. Thanks

```
Private Function SpecialCells(ByVal R As Range, ByVal Typ As XlCellType, _

Optional ByVal Value As XlSpecialCellsValue = &H17) As Range

'Avoid the SpecialCells-BUG to return all cells from the current region

 On Error Resume Next

Select Case Typ

Case xlCellTypeConstants, xlCellTypeFormulas

  Set SpecialCells = Intersect(R, R.SpecialCells(Typ, Value))

Case Else

  Set SpecialCells = Intersect(R, R.SpecialCells(Typ))

End Select

End Function
```

'''Lock all sheet (Function to lock all sheets)

```
Sub protect_all_sheets()

top:

pass = InputBox("password?")

repass = InputBox("Verify Password")

If Not (pass = repass) Then

MsgBox "you made a boo boo"

GoTo top

End If

For i = 1 To Worksheets.Count

If Worksheets(i).ProtectContents = True Then GoTo oops

Next

For Each s In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets

s.Unprotect

s.UsedRange.FormulaHidden = False

Set R = SpecialCells(s.UsedRange, xlCellTypeFormulas)

If R Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

R.FormulaHidden = True

R.Locked = True

s.Protect Password:=pass

Next

Exit Sub

oops: MsgBox "I think you have some sheets that are already protected. Please unprotect all 
sheets then running this Macro."

End Sub
```

Comment: Any workbook can be opened without activating macro's so relying on VBA for security is bad practice. You would be better creating a hidden password protected resource sheet that another sheet just reads the values from.

Comment: Hi @Tragamor Thanks for your time on it. I would like to inform you that I  am completely new to the VBA subject.

My concern isn't over security as it's in the local machine. However, the code protecting few sheets of the workbook and a few are still open for editing. I have tried the below code without any logic and it does work for all sheets.  I am looking for guidance on whether I did any mistake with the above code.

' Protect All Worksheets
Sub ProtectAllSheets()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
 
    For Each ws In Worksheets
        ws.Protect "password"
    Next ws
 
End Sub